# Probability issue given a Bayesian Network

Tags: probability, probability-theory, bayesian-network

If we have a Bayesian Network A -> B ->C then P(B|A, C) = P(B|A)?

Thanks!

Comment: What makes you think that?

Comment: Then what is the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps

$P(B|A,C)=\dfrac{P(A,B,C)}{P(A,B,C)+P(A,\text{not }B,C)}=\dfrac{P(B|A)P(C|B)}{P(B|A)P(C|B)+P(\text{not }B|A)P(C|\text{not }B)}$